# VBA WebScraping Script Returns Subscript OutOf Range

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

#### Problem:

I've been trying to scrape data from a WebSite, but it's always giving me an error **Subscript OutOf Range**. I don't know why. I use the exact same code for another website and it works perfectly fine.

Yes, I've changed the `divs` from the new website I want to scrape from.

#### Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Loiça()
    Dim data As Object, i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, r As Long, c As Long, item As Object, div As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument                  '<== VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library

    Const START_URL As String = "https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", START_URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Dim numPages As Long, numResults As Long, arr() As String
        arr = Split(html.querySelector(".snize-search-results-header").innerText, Chr$(32))
        numResults = arr(UBound(arr))
        numPages = 1


        For i = 1 To numPages
             If i > 1 Then
                .Open "GET", Replace$("https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1", "page=1", "page=" & i), False
                .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
                .send
                 html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            End If
            Set data = html.getElementsByClassName("snize-four-columns")
            For Each item In data
                r = r + 1: c = 1
                For Each div In item.getElementsByTagName("div")
                    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loiça")
                        .Cells(r, c) = div.innerText
                    End With
                    c = c + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @QHarr the error occurs on line 15 `numResults = arr(UBound(arr))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
html.querySelector(".snize-search-results-header").innerText
```

is returning an empty string, therefore when you do split you end up with a -1 in your arr.

It may be that this value requires javascript to run on page. Inspect the returned html. I think no value is returned for that. Use a method like selenium or IE which allows js to run on the page and update content with the value

In this case you also need the lbound so you could use a function that returns the value which uses IE

```
numPages  =  GetNumberOfPages 

Public Function GetNumberOfPages() As Long
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .Navigate2 "https://mediamarkt.pt/pages/search-results-page?q=maquina+roupa&page=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim numPages As Long, numResults As Long, arr() As String
        arr = Split(.document.querySelector(".snize-search-results-header").innerText, Chr$(32))
        numResults = arr(LBound(arr))
        GetNumberOfPages =  numResults
        .Quit
    End With
End Function
```

For the next page you are looking at a different class name (I think)

```
Set data = html.getElementsByClassName("snize-product")
```

Inspect the html to verify.

Comment: By using IE you mean changing the `.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"` to `.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "internetexplorer.application"` because I've already tried that too :/

Comment: No I mean as per my edit above. You can always write the response from your original xmlhttp to a file and inspect. I don't think your value is there but I cannot test here. I am suggesting use a function like above to get the numPages using IE/Selenium then continue with xmlhttp as before assuming required data is returned in .responseText of those requests.

Comment: I was able to get the numResults now thank you, now I just need to figure how to scrap the values into the sheet.

Comment: you need to loop the elements with class name snize-product

Comment: Yes I know that, it isn't giving me any error now and i check the value of `numResults` and it's totally correct!
The only problem now it's that it isn't scraping any result to excel :/

Comment: post a new question but before that inspect the .responseText from xmlhttp and check the data you want is present for those classes. If not, you will need to change the function into a sub and re-write so whole thing done with ie. You can use same structure as your existing code but work with ie object instead.